# How to find documentation for ActiveRecord::Base.update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the process of finding the documentation for a method in Ruby/Rails api http://api.rubyonrails.org/ .

Let's take method `ActiveRecord::Base.update` as an example. It is used in one of the railscasts.

1. There is no mention of update in the api doc for the class
   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html
2. There's
   nothing about `update` method in the source code for Base 
   https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0065f378262dc3f47880ce6211c7474bc7d11f0b/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb
3. In fact, I can't even find this method in any classes included in
   `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I suspect this method is in ActiveRecord::Relation. However, I'm not sure.

I'm a beginner in Ruby/Rails, and I come from Java world, where I would normally expect to see all methods (inherited as well) in a javadoc for the class. What is the most effective finding relevant documentation for mixed-in/inherited methods in case of Ruby/Rails?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in which rails cast it's used?

Comment: Backbone.js railcasts. Here's the link to the code https://github.com/railscasts/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2/blob/master/raffler-after/app/controllers/entries_controller.rb

Comment: +1 I'm astonished at the difficulty of simply finding documentation on the "model".all method, and at how the responders' first reaction was to answer about update when you were clearly asking about the general case. Javadoc 1 - api.rubyonrails.org 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't find any good documentation about `ActiveRecord::Base#update` because the method has been deprecated since Rails version 2.3.8, according to [APIdock.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class).

The reason you can still use it is because it has been moved to `ActiveRecord::Relation` which can be seen in `rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb`.

`rails/activerecord/lib/active_record.rb` contains all the `autoload`s for `ActiveRecord` which includes `:Relation`.

The documentation for `ActiveRecord::Relation#update` is as follows:

> Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database,
>   if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the
>   object was saved successfully to the database or not.
>
> ==== Parameters
>
> - +id+ - This should be the id or an array of ids to be updated.
> - +attributes+ - This should be a hash of attributes or an array of hashes.
>
> ==== Examples

```
# Updates one record 
Person.update(15, :user_name => 'Samuel', :group => 'expert')

# Updates multiple records 
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }       
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

EDIT: To answer your initial question, under most circumstances, doing a search on [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) is enough to find the information you are looking for, as long as the information is up-to-date.

For potentially older API details, use [apidock.com/rails](http://apidock.com/rails). Doing a search there for 'update' actually shows both versions (`::Base` and `::Relation`) and gives you details about each and what version of Rails each are used in.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it was just moved to a mixin, away from the ActiveRecord::Base code. This method works and I'm pretty sure I'm using Rails 3.2.3. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That explains why it works. Thanks. However, the original question was more about the process of finding a doc for a method. Is there a way to find out that `update` is in `Relation` without actually knowing rails code?

Comment: I added an edit that points out using APIdock over the official documentation since it includes past versions of Rails which can be very handy while learning from tutorials that are even just a few years old.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing without looking at code, that Relation#update is invoked when invoking Base#update? From the apidock it seems that there is no such method in the new version at all.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::Base.update doesn't exist anymore as you can see here : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class, it's ActiveRecord::Relation now as here : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update

Comment: If it does not exist, then why does it work? See my comment on Charles Caldwell's answer.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base include ActiveRecore::Relation's methods. See the sources : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0065f378262dc3f47880ce6211c7474bc7d11f0b/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb